# cannot get data to javascript from php DB

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysqli

I am quite new to JavaScript and PHP.

I have started lately on my free time to develop a chrme extension to grab some data from db on a hosting server.

I have created a php file and upload it to the server, this file will be called from my extension js file and will connect to the DB to execute a query and return the result back.

everything goes fine except I dnt see the data, it keeps sending me null info.

Connection is ok, credentials are good but somiething is missing.

PHP code:

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

$name = $_POST['name'];

$servername = "139.162.132.71";
$username = "evhoodco_EVhdAdm";
$password = "******";
$dbname = "evhoodco_EVhd623Vehicles";

// Create connection

$dbhandle = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if (!$dbhandle)
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
else{
    echo "Success to connect to MySQL";
}

$result = $dbhandle->query("SELECT 1");

if ( false===$result ) {
  printf("error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
}
else {
  echo ' ... done...';
}

echo json_encode($result);

mysqli_close($dbhandle);
?>
```

JavaScript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $.post('http://evhood.com/connDB.php','name=bob').done(function(data){
           chrome.bookmarks.create({'parentId': "1",'title': '','url': "http://www.sapo.pt"}); 
           console.log(data);    

        });

});
```

And this is the debug window result:

[image: debug]

Comment: `SELECT 1` ?? Try with something like `SELECT * FROM tablename` where tablename is the name you gave to the table you target in your database.

Comment: Hi Louys, yes I just put SELECT 1 cos the result is sure to be 1, so I could test, but instead I receive NULL